# How to detect the event component is being loaded in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, loading, angular-routing

I have lazy loaded a module in my angular 4 app.
Now this module has various components loaded inside it using its own routing.
I want to show a loader before each component is loaded.
I tried different router events. below component is the root component of this lazy loaded module.

```
constructor(
private router: Router
) {
  router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
    this.navigationInterceptor(event)
   })
}

navigationInterceptor(event: RouterEvent): void {
    this.routeLoading=true;
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      this.routeLoading = true;
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      this.routeLoading = false;
    }

    // Set loading state to false in both of the below events to hide the loading bar if routing error is thrown.
    if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
      this.routeLoading = false;
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
      this.routeLoading = false;
    }
}
```

And In my view I am doing something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="routeLoading">
  <md-progress-bar  [color]="color" [mode]="mode" [value]="value" [bufferValue]="bufferValue"></md-progress-bar>
</div>
```

But problem here is this events gets resolved too soon. and loader does not appear even if view is not loaded. I mean screen is blank before component is loaded & loader doesnt appear.

Comment: where is loader html code

Comment: i think first time you should take  this.routeLoading=false;

Comment: @soumya I have written the loader code below

Comment: Your logic is correct , please make sure you have placed progress bar in app component.